# How to create posts from each image in bulk?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

So here is my problem statement:

I have a folder with more than 2000 images. I want them to upload on wordpress with one post created corresponding to each image, and the image should be as attachment.

It would take me forever to do that. Can any one one suggest any relevant plugins for that ?

Can I do that programmatically ? ( But I guess that won't be able to utilize wordpress features like thumbnail generation etc. )

Comment: Did you even look at the WP Codex? [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [add_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)?

Comment: Thanks. But can I use these functions via xml-rpc apis ?

Comment: Well, I think that won't solve my case. I want to make a script using their APIs.

Comment: Did you even look at the WP Codex? [XML-RPC support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support). There's no reason not to use the Wordpress API to handle your wordpress related issues. If you're not leveraging the API from Wordpress, then you're doing it wrong and should reconsider your work flow.

Comment: Yes, I had looked at WP Codex. It doesn't have function for thumbnail creation while uploading media file. Please correct if I am wrong.